# Passenger and Nginx :unix:/tmp/passenger.MGo50AR/agents.s/core failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, passenger

I'm new to **passenger/ Nginx**, 
I have my rails application running at Nginx and passenger. Some time my application stops working and I got these errors at my nginx error.log file:

```
App 19637 stderr:  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/platform_info.rb:363: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0 in PATH, mode 042777
App 19637 stderr:  [passenger_native_support.so] trying to compile for the current user (nobody) and Ruby interpreter...
App 19637 stderr:
App 19637 stderr:      (set PASSENGER_COMPILE_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
App 19637 stderr:
App 19637 stderr:      Warning: compilation didn't succeed. To learn why, read this file:
App 19637 stderr:
App 19637 stderr:      /tmp/passenger_native_support-2s90v9.log
App 19637 stderr:
App 19637 stderr:  [passenger_native_support.so] finding downloads for the current Ruby interpreter...
App 19637 stderr:
App 19637 stderr:      (set PASSENGER_DOWNLOAD_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
App 19637 stderr:
App 19637 stderr:      Could not download https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/binaries/passenger/by_release/5.2.3/rubyext-ruby-2.4.0-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
App 19637 stderr:      Trying next mirror...
App 19637 stderr:      Could not download https://s3.amazonaws.com/phusion-passenger/binaries/passenger/by_release/5.2.3/rubyext-ruby-2.4.0-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden
App 19637 stderr:  [passenger_native_support.so] will not be used (can't compile or download)


0 11:07:05 [crit] 6591#6591: *217 connect() to unix:/tmp/passenger.MGo50AR/agents.s/core failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 122.160.67.201, server: 58.98.163.42, request: "POST /customerBadgesCounts HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/tmp/passenger.MGo50AR/agents.s/core:", host: "58.98.163.42:3001"
2018/04/10 11:07:05 [crit] 6591#6591: *217 connect() to unix:/tmp/passenger.MGo50AR/agents.s/core failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 122.160.67.201, server: 58.98.163.42, request: "POST /updated/branches/search HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/tmp/passenger.MGo50AR/agents.s/core:", host: "58.98.163.42:3001"
2018/04/10 11:07:25 [crit] 6591#6591: *220 connect() to unix:/tmp/passenger.MGo50AR/agents.s/core failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 122.160.67.201, server: 58.98.163.42, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/tmp/passenger.MGo50AR/agents.s/core:", host: "mydomain.com:3001"
2018/04/10 11:07:42 [crit] 6591#6591: *224 connect() to unix:/tmp/passenger.MGo50AR/agents.s/core failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 122.177.174.65, server: 58.98.163.42, request: "POST /suggestsearch HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/tmp/passenger.MGo50AR/agents.s/core:", host: "58.98.163.42:3001"
2018/04/10 11:07:42 [crit] 6592#6592: *226 connect() to unix:/tmp/passenger.MGo50AR/agents.s/core failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 122.177.174.65, server: 58.98.163.42, request: "POST /customerBadgesCounts HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/tmp/passenger.MGo50AR/agents.s/core:", host: "58.98.163.42:3001"
2018/04/10 11:07:42 [crit] 6592#6592: *228 connect() to unix:/tmp/passenger.MGo50AR/agents.s/core failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 122.177.174.65, server: 58.98.163.42, request: "POST /updated/home HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/tmp/passenger.MGo50AR/agents.s/core:", host: "58.98.163.42:3001"
2018/04/10 11:09:05 [crit] 6591#6591: *230 connect() to unix:/tmp/passenger.MGo50AR/agents.s/core failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 122.160.67.201, server: 58.98.163.42, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/tmp/passenger.MGo50AR/agents.s/core:", host: "mydomain.com:1111"
2018/04/10 11:09:15 [crit] 6591#6591: *234 connect() to unix:/tmp/passenger.MGo50AR/agents.s/core failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 122.160.67.201, server: 58.98.163.42, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/tmp/passenger.MGo50AR/agents.s/core:", host: "mydomain.com:3001"
```

I'm not getting whats I have made wrong there!

Please help me and suggest a way to moveout from here.

Comment: How do you solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is 4 years late but yesterday I had a similar issue. I solved it by running `sudo service nginx restart` .